# PostgreSQL insert query using jsonb data type

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, jsonb

I'm trying to use JSONB data type in PostgreSQL for my `product` table, like the following example:

[image]

Then, when I execute the below INSERT query for this table, the query is not executed !

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT 
VALUES 
(7, 'iPhone8', 'Grey', 700.00, 34, '{"storage": 256, "RAM": 16, "resolution": 1700X456 }')
```

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot double quotes in value "1700X456" (it is a string, not a number).

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT 
VALUES 
(7, 'iPhone8', 'Grey', 700.00, 34, '{"storage": 256, "RAM": 16, "resolution": "1700X456" }')
```